# Rollback if one update failed in 2 models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models that I want to update
let say I have Transaction and Product

I want to update Transaction first and then Product
but I failed to update Product for some reasons, can I rollback Product and Transactions as well in rails ?? and how ? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is put it in a single transaction. if any error occurs, it roll backs all operations made in the block

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @transaction.save!
    @product.save!
  end
  #handle success here
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
   #handle failure here
end
```

Comment: have you tried it ? should i raise ActiveRecord::Rollback also?

Comment: No need for a Rollback. If any error occurs in the block, like validation or any kind. It will roll back the changes made. technically they aren't made until the block goes through without an error.

Comment: You can try this in the Rails Console - rails c

Comment: i have two method : update_transaction and update_product , on each methods do update, and i wrap `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do  update_transaction 
  update_product end` if one of them fail, will it make error result on my controller ? because after that thee is another logic that i should render as well after them

Comment: i just consider that method only for Rails 6 ? i am using rails 4, will it work ??

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.transaction this is pretty old, should work fine.

Comment: You can change the rescue to Rollback if you want to, you might wanna rather be error specific, instead of a roll back. with `@transaction.errors and @product.errors`